# Can't find build app for Windows in flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I want to build app for windows. Command worked fine, but in the official docs it says after building app for windows should Release's folder appear, but as you can see on the screenshot where is no folder with such name after the build. What I did wrong?

[image: screenshot with problem]

My pubspec.yaml file:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'
```

Comment: the folder is on the root , not in the `windows`  directory.

Comment: its same when we build for  `android`. the apk file was not found in the `android` directory.

Comment: I found it. It was simple, and I found my exe file through out the search